# Border until text content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add border to the text in the menu. What I want is to have the borders width as long as the text. I have achieved this for single line menu items.

[image]

As you see in the screen the menu item "test av lister" has correct border width but the next item has more width. I want the width to stop where the first line is ending.

Here is my css to achieve this so far

```
.mp-pusher .title__content {
   border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
   width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: This is not possible with borders as the containing display-box wrapper is *always* wider than the text when text wraps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to acheive by any other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you think about all of those elements being a box, you can see why the border is moving across the entire element.

```
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Here's an example of what is happening:

```
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bmLj7fo0/

*also:* I'm not sure that 'fit-content' and those width properties are *ready to be used* yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width . You can see a little 'mad scientist' potion next to the options that are experimental.

As a user... I'd find that visual treatment weird. Maybe you can dream up a new visual style for the smallest screens. : )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I really appreciate the explanation. Is there any other way to acheive it?

Comment: I tried for 10 minutes or so - but couldn't come up with anything. : /

Comment: I achieved it with a combnation of jquery and background-image plus background-size.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it by using this css

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #F16A70, #F16A70);
background-position: bottom left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 50% 2px;
transition: background-size .5s ease;
```

and this jquery

```
$.fn.textWidth = function () {
    var html_org = $(this).html();
    var html_calc = '<span>' + html_org + '</span>';
    $(this).html(html_calc);
    var width = $(this).find('span:first').width();
    $(this).html(html_org);
    return width;
};

// added JS trick to make the border of the menu items just so that they are the size of the item
$(".title__content.pb-1").each(function () {
    var tW = $(this).textWidth();
    $(this).css('background-size', tW + 'px 3px');
});
```